# Select Max value from sublist with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How to write a LINQ query that would return row of type "Value" with Max Date and Max value for that date. it should be the row where name = "Correct"

I've written a query at the end, and it working, just trying to find a correct way of doing this.

Thanks in advance

```
public class MeasurePoint
{
    public int No { get; set; }
    public string Weight { get; set; }
    public List<Values> Vals { get; set; }
}

public class Values
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Val { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public static class Test
{
    public static void Calc()
    {
        var mps = new List<MeasurePoint>();

        mps.Add(new MeasurePoint()
        {
            No = 1,
            Vals = new List<Values>()
            {
                new Values(){Date = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1), Name = "testas", Val = 1},
                new Values(){Date = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(2), Name = "testas", Val = 5},
                new Values(){Date = DateTime.Now.Date, Name = "testas", Val = 15}
            }});
        mps.Add(new MeasurePoint()
        {
            No = 2,
            Vals = new List<Values>()
            {
                new Values(){Date = DateTime.Now.Date, Name = "testas", Val = 11},
                new Values(){Date = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(2), Name = "Correct", Val = 55},
                new Values(){Date = DateTime.Now.Date, Name = "testas", Val = 15}
            }
        });
        mps.Add(new MeasurePoint()
        {
            No = 3,
            Vals = new List<Values>()
            {
                new Values(){Date = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1), Name = "testas", Val = 111},
                new Values(){Date = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(2), Name = "testas", Val = 52},
                new Values(){Date = DateTime.Now.Date, Name = "testas", Val = 15}
            }
        });

        mps.Add(new MeasurePoint()
        {
            No = 4,
            Vals = new List<Values>()                      
        });

        var x = mps.ElementAt(0).Vals.Union(mps.ElementAt(1).Vals).Union(mps.ElementAt(2).Vals);
        var z = x.Where(p => p.Date == x.Max(d => d.Date)).MaxBy(t=>t.Val);

        //One more way I've found
        var ttt = mps.SelectMany(p => p.Vals).GroupBy(t=>t.Date).MaxBy(r=>r.Key).MaxBy(g=>g.Val);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var max = mps.SelectMany(x => x.Vals)
    .Aggregate((a, x) => (x.Date > a.Date) ||
                         ((x.Date == a.Date) && (x.Val > a.Val)) ? x : a);
```

Comment: @Martynas: `SelectMany` simply "flattens" your original collection into a single sequence containing all the `Values` objects from the `Vals` collections of all the `MeasurePoint` objects. `Aggregate` then steps through the flattened sequence, comparing each element to the max (so far). If the current element is greater than the max then that becomes the new max. Once all elements have been processed the max is returned.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var result = mps.Where(m => m.Vals.Count > 0)
    .SelectMany(m => m.Vals
        .OrderByDescending(v => v.Date)
        .Take(1), (m, v) => new {m.No, v.Date, v.Name, v.Val});
```

**EDIT** - this is a new version as issue has become more clear

```
var result = mps.Where(m => m.Vals.Count > 0)
    .SelectMany(m => m.Vals)
    .OrderByDescending(v => v.Date)
    .ThenByDescending(v => v.Val).Take(1);
```

Comment: Am, this would be correct if I'd need to find record by Max date, but it also needs to find a max "Val" for that date. But the Your idea is nice :) thanks

Comment: Cool :) Will try all of them, to see which one give the best performace :)

Comment: I've accepted Lukeh's answer, because it gives a better performance.

Answer (score 0):

How can use call `MaxBy()` if it's a method of `IObservable<T>` meanwhile `GroupBy()` returns `IEnumerable<T>` ?

Comment: Heh :) I've installed Reactive Linq Extensions and totally forgot about them :)

Comment: @Martynas: Please mention that in your post to make it more clear :)